# Problem with migration to version 7 and artifacts

Tags: artifactory, conan

We have a problem with a migration of Artifactory CE for C\C++ from version 6.6.5 to 7.49.3. The steps marked on its website were carried out.

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Upgrading+Artifactory

First it went to version 6.10.1 and then version 7

Apparently the migration was successful, but when running commands with conan it gives some problems.

The first is that although the conan user command perfectly recognizes the LDAP user, when executing a conan install, it asks for the user's password and, even if it is entered correctly, it does not recognize it.

The second is that if you use an internal user, the conan install runs correctly as long as the artifacts are from dates after the migration, with those from an earlier date it fails because it doesn't recognize that they exist even though you can view and download them from artifacts. perfectly

Could it be known what these errors are due to?

Comment: It seems that even if the migration seemed to have completed successfully, it didn't, and some packages are corrupt. If you have access to the previous state or backup, maybe downloading everything first with the client, then re-uploading once it is migrated could help to fix things.

Comment: did you migrate to V2?
https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-force-conan-migration-from-v1-to-v2/